# How to update a list of objects in Django with a unique constraint?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to update a list of objects with a unique constraint but an exception is raised.
Is it possible deferring a constraint using Django ORM?

This is what I have tried:

```py
class Episode(models.Model):
    issue_date = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, unique=True)
    ...
```

```py
def rearrange_episodes(cls, programme, after):
    next_episodes = Episode.objects.filter(programme=programme, issue_date__gte=after).order_by('issue_date')
    for episode in next_episodes:
        episode.issue_date = get_next_date()
        episode.save() #Crash -> Duplicate entry
```

Comment: [Try using transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/). Take care of choosing the right Django version in the selector in the right-bottom corner.

Comment: What is `get_next_day()`, show exeception traceback and what is your desired result?

Comment: The problem is an episode.issue.date overlaps with another episode during the rearrange

Answer (score 1):

If `get_next_date()` is returning dates that already exist then you have a problem that can't be solved.

I assume instead that you want to shift the dates along 'by one episode'
i.e.

```
episode[0].issue_date --> episode[1].issue_date
episode[1].issue_date --> episode[2].issue_date
episode[2].issue_date --> new date
```

...which you have tried to do as above but it is failing at the first step because `episode[1].issue_date` already exists.

To solve this you just need to iterate in reverse order so that:

```
episode[2].issue_date --> new date
episode[1].issue_date --> previous episode[2].issue_date
episode[0].issue_date --> previous episode[1].issue_date
```

assuming your `get_next_date()` function will work under this circumstance you can just change your code to:

```
def rearrange_episodes(cls, programme, after):
    next_episodes = Episode.objects.filter(programme=programme, issue_date__gte=after).order_by('-issue_date')
    for episode in next_episodes:
        episode.issue_date = get_next_date()
        episode.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not valid for my problem, because the rearrange is not lineal.

For example:

```
episode[4].issue_date --> new date 
episode[3].issue_date --> previous episode[4].issue_date 
episode[2].issue_date --> not change
episode[1].issue_date --> previous episode[0].issue_date
episode[0].issue_date --> new date
```

I only see two easy ways to solve the problem, remove the constraint or delete and create the objects using [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)